# What do you think about this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

It was from English exam of Japanese so-called SAT.

“When Ayano came to my house, it happened that nobody was at home.”

Is it fine english? I’d like to hear your opinions.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that sentence & the variations ( some listed by Peter Jennings & FumbleFingers ) which are all valid based on context. Eg "What happened when Ayano came to your house ?" OR "Why was Ayano angry after visiting your house ?" OR "Why was Ayano sitting outside your house ?" : Each of these may have the same response with Different wordings. Example Query : "Do you know when Ayano came to your house ?" & Example Answer : "Well, when Ayano came to my home, it happened that nobody was at home. This is when we all go out to lunch. Hence , I guess Ayano must have come around Noon" !

Answer (score 4):

Yes that's OK grammatically.
It is not as common as saying

> When Ayano came to my house, unfortunately / fortunately nobody was at
> home.

Or even just

> When Ayano came to my house, nobody was at home.

It can also be worded

> When Ayano came to my house, it **so** happened nobody was at
> home.

All mean pretty much the same thing.

Comment: We're [increasingly likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+so+happened%2Cit+just+so+happened&year_start=1999&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) to include the intensifier in *It **just** so happened that [something relatively unlikely]*.